# I want to convert xml string data inside json object to json in java

Tags: java, json

Below is my json string and i want to convert data of additionalDetails into json string, but i am not able to success.

```
{
  "docs": 70,
  "size": 250,
  "currentPageNo": 0,
  "recordStartFrom": 0,
  "columnHeader": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "fieldName": "id",
      "imgName": "",
      "tooltipSrc": "",
    }
    ],
    "data": [
    {
      "Number": "10000",
      "price": "4.75",
      "manfName": "",
      "minOrderQty": "0.00",
      "maxOrderQty": "0",
      "additionalDetails": "<item>CUR:Rupees</item><item>code:one</item>",
    },
    {
      "Number": "10001",
      "price": "1.75",
      "manfName": "",
      "minOrderQty": "0.00",
      "maxOrderQty": "0",
      "additionalDetails": "",
    }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to convert additionalDetails data into json string. I try to convert json string to XML content and XML to json string but data of additionalDetails is not converted into json string.

Comment: If you are trying please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Actually, the value of "additionalDetails" is already a String.  What I assume you want to do is convert that String into a Map using an XML parser, then insert that Map into the parsed JSON Map/List "tree" where the original String was.  After that, if desired, the entire tree can be serialized back into JSON string form.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a general solution to the stated problem, but a solution to your problem.

I would use regular expressions along the lines of:

```
<item>([0-9a-zA-Z]*):([0-9a-zA-Z]*)</item>
```

If you use this expression in global mode you will match each input. You can parse the string using [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). (See the section on "Groups and capturing" to get the values within.)

You can then build up a [com.google.gson.JsonArray](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) and populate the values from the Matcher. This array can then be replaced with the `additionalDetails` field.

Finally you just write out the result or do whatever you wanted to do with it.

Comment: Hi rioki thanks for reply, I want to convert <item>CUR:Rupees</item><item>code:one</item> into json same as "data" array.

Comment: What library are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: I am using gson 2.2.3 library file

Comment: I went into some additional detail, hope it is clear now how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared some [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PKBB7/3/) for You using [**X2JS**](http://code.google.com/p/x2js/) library: http://code.google.com/p/x2js/

**INDEX.HTML:**

```
<body>
    <pre id="pre_id">TEST</pre>
    <button id="go_button">GO</button>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
var x2js = new X2JS();

$("#go_button").click(function() {
    var form_data = {
      "docs": 70,
      "size": 250,
      "currentPageNo": 0,
      "recordStartFrom": 0,
      "columnHeader": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "fieldName": "id",
          "imgName": "",
          "tooltipSrc": "",
        }
        ],
        "data": [
        {
          "Number": "10000",
          "price": "4.75",
          "manfName": "",
          "minOrderQty": "0.00",
          "maxOrderQty": "0",
          "additionalDetails": "<item>CUR:Rupees</item><item>code:one</item>",
        },
        {
          "Number": "10001",
          "price": "1.75",
          "manfName": "",
          "minOrderQty": "0.00",
          "maxOrderQty": "0",
          "additionalDetails": "",
        }
        ]
    };
    for (var i=0; i<form_data.data.length; i++) {
        console.log(x2js.xml_str2json(
            '<additionalDetails>'+
            form_data.data[i].additionalDetails+
            '</additionalDetails>'));
        form_data.data[i].additionalDetails = x2js.xml_str2json(
            '<additionalDetails>'+
            form_data.data[i].additionalDetails+
            '</additionalDetails>').additionalDetails;
    }
    $('#pre_id').html(JSON.stringify(form_data));
});
```

Comment: Hi WBAR thanks for your reply,but I want to do this in java it is working fine in javascript.